# How do I dynamically add og:image meta tags in drupal multisite

Tags: 8, multi-sites, meta-tags

I have drupal 8 multisite setup, where I am creating multiple site using some script technique and rendering the data using domain name via twig files by fetching from dynamodb records.

So my question is how do I add /update meta tags dynamically in my theme template files to preview thumbnail when I share any node on social media.
I want to display the site logo after fetching it from dynamodb records. As of now it is displaying some random image from network of the website page.

Comment: Have you looked at the metatag and it's open graph submodule?  This can automatically generate Meta information using tokens based on the current page.  With your custom setup, you may need to create some custom tokens but that is not hard to do.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am working on multisites and for dozens of site I can not enable the module for each site manually and do the rest config via submodule. Is there any way to do it dynamically?